# Generate a list (including missing values) from a Pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the simple Pandas data frame I'm using:

```
>>> df2
    Name  Day  Score
0  Allen    1     25
5  Allen    3      9
```

What I'm trying to do is generate a list of Allen's scores, and also signal days when there is no score for all days from 1 to 5. Here's what I've been able to do:

```
>>> [df2[df2['Day']==i]['Score'].values[0] if i in list(df2['Day']) else None for i in range(1,6)]
[25, None, 9, None, None]
```

Surely there's a less clunky way to do this? **What is it?**

On a related note, I'd like to do this for each person in a larger data frame. What's the best way to do that? For now all I can think of is using **apply** with the expression above, but again that seems clunkier than this should have to be. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I would start by setting the index to 'Day' and re-indexing:

```
>>> df2 = df2.set_index('Day').reindex(range(1,6))

      Name  Score
Day              
1    Allen     25
2      NaN    NaN
3    Allen      9
4      NaN    NaN
5      NaN    NaN
```

From there you have lots of options for proceding further.  If you just want a list:

```
>>> df2['Score'].tolist()

[25.0, nan, 9.0, nan, nan]
```

You may want to look at `fillna()` for different options on specifying the missing value.

Comment: I don't understand what role reindexing played?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck changes index from [0,5] to [1,2,3,4,5].  Look at the OP's original data.

Comment: Sure, but why is resetting an index necessary?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  It's not necessary in and of itself, it's just an intermediate step I used to get the answer here.  If you have an alternative approach that you like better I would sincerely encourage you to post it.  This was merely the best I could come up with at the time and I haven't looked at this since I originally posted it (so my overall memory of this is quite hazy)